# dynamic forms in django with ajax/dajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have this simple form with a queryset to display job objects and allow the user to select one.  Now, i would like to have a group of two radio buttons that would allow the user to select a 'filtering option'.  If the user selects a group filter with the radio buttons, i would a drop down to appear that allows them to select which group they would like to filter on.  I want to do this without having to reload the page, so i'm attempting to use dajax.

I was able to find an example on the dajax website that does something similiar, however, i was not able to get it to work.  The radio buttons appear and the drop down appears(empty).  When i click on the "Group" radio button, the drop-down should populate with all my Group objects, but it doesnt.

I've been stuck on this for awhile, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**forms.py**

```
filters = (('0', 'Group'), 
           ('1', 'Host'), 
          )

class JobSelectForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['jobs'].widget.attrs["size"] = 20
    jobs = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Job.objects.all().order_by('name'), empty_label=None,)
    filter = forms.ChoiceField(choices=filters,
                               widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'onchange': "Dajaxice.tdportal.updatefilter(Dajax.process,{'option':this.value})", 'name':'combo1', 'id':'combo1', }, 
                                                        renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),
```

**ajax.py**

```
def updatefilter(request, option):
    dajax = Dajax()
    options = [Group.objects.all(),
               Host.objects.all(),
               ]
    out = ""
    for o in options[int(option)]:
        out = "%s<option value='#'>%s" % (out,o,)

    dajax.assign('#combo2','innerHTML',out)
    return dajax.json()

dajaxice_functions.register(updatefilter)
```

**template**

```
    {{selectForm.filter.label}}: {{selectForm.filter}}
    <br>
    <select name="combo2" id="combo2" onchange="" size="1"></select>
    <br><br>
    <form method="post" action="/tdportal/jobs/">{% csrf_token %}
        {{selectForm.jobs}}
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />   <a href="/tdportal/jobs/new/"><input type="button" name="new" value="New" /></a>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your dajaxice function to the select `onchange` to reference your function in the template.

Something like:

```
<select name="combo2" id="combo2" onchange="Dajaxice.your_project.your_appname.updatefilter(Dajax.process,{'option':this.value}" size="1"></select>
```

(Replace your_project with your project name, your_app with your appname).

Also make sure in your template you have all the necessary headers (and that they actually are there; e.g., if you view the source that you can click to them).

Be sure to debug using google chrome inspector (Ctrl-Shift-I) or firebug (in firefox).

EDIT: I now noticed that you have something similar that's in your form.  How does it render in the HTML when you view the source?  Is it improperly escaped?

Comment: ah ha!  the single quotes around "option" are rendering as "#39;"  Any advice on how to escape them in the forms.py?

Comment: Ok, i fixed the escaping issue by using mark_safe to set the attrs in the form object.  it renders now.  But still no working... :-(

Comment: @nnachefski: Do you have all the correct headers in the HTML source?  'dajaxice.core.js', 'jquery.core.js', 'jquery-???.min.js' (or whatever library you use)?  Also can you try changing: 'Dajaxice.tdportal.updatefilter' to 'Dajaxice.project_name.app_name.updatefilter' in 'onchange' (replacing with appropriate names)?  I definitely have to specify the project and app names to get it to work on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot a `%` sign (`value='#'`) and a closing `</option>` in here:

`out = "%s<option value='%s'>%s</option>" % (out,o,o)`

Comment: thanks, i fixed the options rendering.  This code was from an example i saw and i guess it wasnt proper.  :-)